# Problem with number of selections in uicollectionviewcells inside a tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift

When I want to return a certain amount of UIcollectionviewcells inside a UITableViewCell it acts in such a strange way I just can't figure out the problem, after the first three cells everything just starts to become a mess, it starts returning the same values as the first two, for a better explanation:

var Count: [Int] = [2,3,4,5,6]
- The first UITableViewCell give me 2 uicollectionviews as it should based on the Count array. 
- The second UITableViewCell give me 3 uicollectionviews as it should based on the Count array. 
- The third UITableViewCell give me 4 uicollectionviews as it should based on the Count array. 
- The fourth UITableViewCell give me 2 uicollectionviews and according to my count array it should be 5 but it just decides not to.
- The fifth UITableViewCell give me 3 uicollectionviews and according to my count array it should be 6 but it just decides not to.

- I have tried making it so the count array is based on my own separate int value and it still does the same.
- I have tried using a programed uicollectionview instead of using the storyboard and it just did the samething.

var Count: [Int] = [2,3,4,5,6]

class Projects: UITableViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    SetUp()
}

func SetUp() {
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

}

extension Projects {

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let Cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    print(indexPath.row)
    Cell.CollectionCount = Count[indexPath.row]
    Cell.ProjectText = "Hello"
    return Cell
}
```

}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var ProjectLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!

var ProjectText: String?
var CollectionCount: Int?

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    ProjectLabel.text = ProjectText!
    CollectionView.delegate = self
    CollectionView.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return CollectionCount!
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let Cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    return Cell
}
```

}

- The first UITableViewCell should give me 2 uicollectionviews.
- The second UITableViewCell should give me 3 uicollectionviews.
- The third UITableViewCell should give me 4 uicollectionviews.
- The fourth UITableViewCell should give me 5 uicollectionviews.
- The fifth UITableViewCell should give me 6 uicollectionviews.

Comment: Cells are reused. You need to reload the collection view when you change the `count` property; use a `didSet` observer. Also, by convention in Swift variables and properties start with a lower case letter. Classes, Structs and Protocols start with a capital.  Adopting this convention will make your code clearer for others.